# How to export models in the form of middle ware in main server.js and write routes for tables in separate model.js file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am a newbie in node.I have created a server file to connect mongoDB and wrote routes in the same. Created a model.js for table attributes.I want to write a route for my other tables.

https://codingthesmartway.com/the-mern-stack-tutorial-building-a-react-crud-application-from-start-to-finish-part-2/

Taken reference from here. But want to create a seperate file for connection and add module for tables

This is my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const todoRoutes = express.Router();

const PORT = 4000;
let Todo = require('./todo.model');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/todos', todoRoutes);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/todos', { 
useNewUrlParser: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;


connection.once('open', function() {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established 
successfully");
})

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("Server is running on Port: " + PORT);
});

todoRoutes.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
} else {
res.json(todos);
}
});
});
```

this routes are in this file i want to export it from other model.js

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put route in another file,i would suggest you to make a new folder route and then inside it make a new file by route name(say createUser.js).

In this server.js file only use

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PORT = 4000;
let Todo = require('./todo.model');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/todos', todoRoutes);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/todos', { 
useNewUrlParser: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;


connection.once('open', function() {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established 
successfully");
})

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("Server is running on Port: " + PORT);
});

export default app;
```

And in another file inside route folder use the require imports and  define the route here.

```
 const todoRoutes = express.Router(); 
    todoRoutes.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
    Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
    if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    } else {
    res.json(todos);
    }
    });
    });
    module.exports=todoRoute;
```

Furthur you can import this route in any model.js and use it for implementation of logic.

Note-: You can also use a third folder controllers and implement the route logic there since it is the best practice to not write logic on route but use controller file for it.Also you can separate the DB connection login in another file.

Comment: Getting this error app.use('/todos', todoRoutes); 
ReferenceError: todoRoutes is not defined
in server.js
And when am defining export default app; 
it is giving me error : unexpected export

Comment: Use const app=express.Router(); and app.route('/')... See if this helps....   https://github.com/PragyanshuSharma/ninjago

Comment: Somehow it helped me. Thanks